# How to add Devise error message "someone already signed up with that email"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, devise

When someone tries to signup with an email that already has an account associated with it I would like to show an error message that says "someone already signed up with that email".

How can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your model includes `devise :validatable` and it will take care of itself.

See: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable

Comment: its already there but the error message isn't showing when someone tries signing up with an existing email.

Comment: Is the new record saved?  Do you get a flash message saying 'user successfully created'?  What happens if you try to create a new user in the console?  What happens if you try to do it in a test?  Need more info to troubleshoot further.